# Spring Rest Delete endpoint with empty path variable

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have two endpoints in my rest controller :

```
  @GetMapping("/{userId}")
  public DTO get(@PathVariable @Parameter(description = "user ID") String userId) {
    ...
  }

  @DeleteMapping("/{userId}")
  @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
  public void delete(@PathVariable @Parameter(description = "user ID") String userId) {
    ...
  }`
```

If I call the GET endpoint with an empty userId, it fails and returns a `BadRequestException` which makes sense.

But if I call the DELETE endpoint with an empty userId, it does not raise a `BadRequestException` but rather gets inside the endpoint's code.

Should I change anything to have the same behaviour for the two endpoints ?
Why is there a difference in the way Spring handles the empty path variables ?

Thank you.

Comment: What happens, if you remove `@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)`?

Comment: same behaviour, I already tried that :)

Comment: Do you have an addition Endpoint `  @DeleteMapping("/")` in one of your controller?

Comment: nope, I have 2 endpoints in my controller : @DeleteMapping("/{userId}") and @GetMapping("/{userId}")

Answer (score 0):

I think you have tow endpoints like this  :

```
@GetMapping("/")   public DTO get1() {
    ...   }

@GetMapping("/{userId}")   public DTO get2() String userId) {
    ...   }
```

And when you call your endpoint @GetMapping("/{userId}") without userId, it make the same call for the first endpoint.

Comment: No, I only have one get endpoint (which has userId path variable.
I don't have 
@GetMapping("/")   public DTO get1() {
    ...   }